# Iterating the arraylist and getting row wise list

Tags: arraylist

I am iterating over the `ArrayList` and saving the values like this:

```
operRepList=(List<OperRepDTO>) resultMap.get(CFSConstants.MAP_KEY_RESULT_LIST);

        if(!Utilities.isListNullOrEmpty(operRepList)) {

            for(OperRepDTO A:operRepList) {
                operRepDTO.setComp(A.getComp());
                operRepDTO.setContSize(A.getContSize());
                operRepDTO.setProdType(A.getProdType());
                operRepDTO.setProdDesc(A.getProdDesc());
                operRepDTO.setTon(A.getTon());
                operRepDTO.setNoOfCont(A.getNoOfCont());

            }
        }
```

but while iterating the second value is overlapped with first value, so when it comes to the final value the variable contains only last row value.

How to store row wise list and get in another `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the static setter method sets always the same field therefore you end up with the values from the last iteration. You should post operRepDTO class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not creating the object for each iteration. you are just updating the  operRepDTO object in each iteration hence it is just getting updated with the current row value and at the last iteration it will just contain your last row value.

you should modify your loop as follows  :

```
     List<OperRepDTO> result = new ArrayList<OperRepDTO>(operRepList.size());

     for(OperRepDTO A:operRepList) {

            OperRepDTO operRepDTO = new OperRepDTO ();

            operRepDTO.setComp(A.getComp());

            operRepDTO.setContSize(A.getContSize());

            operRepDTO.setProdType(A.getProdType());

            operRepDTO.setProdDesc(A.getProdDesc());

            operRepDTO.setTon(A.getTon());

            operRepDTO.setNoOfCont(A.getNoOfCont());

            results.add(operRepDTO);

        }
```

So that after the for loop the results arraylist will contain all the values.